# Probability for finding a collision

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

> Assume a process that samples uniformly at random from the range $[1,\ldots,n]$. I am interested in the expected time to find a duplicate given only that the sampling process is pairwise independent. That is I would like to find the expected time until a sample matches one of the samples taken before.
>
> One way to compute the expected time is
>   $$E=\sum_{x=1}^\infty P(X \geq x).$$  Here $X$ is a random variable that represents the time at which the first duplicate is found.
>
> If the samples were fully independent then we would have that  $$\sum_{x=1}^\infty P(X \geq x) = \sum_{x=1}^\infty \prod_{i=1}^{x-1} (1-i/n).$$

I found this answer on here. But why does the product end at $x-1$?

If I understand correctly $P(X \geq x)$ describes the probability that the first k-1 samples are different.

My calculation would look like this

$$P(X \geq x)=\frac{n*(n-1)*...*(n-(k-2))}{n^k}=\prod_{i=1}^{k-2} 1-\frac{i}{n}$$

Reason: The kth sample can be a collision so I only have to restrict the possibilities for the first k-1 samples

Comment: I suspect you are correct  You want the answer $2$ when $n=1$, the answer $\frac52$ when $n=2$ and $\frac{26}{9}$ when $n=3$

Comment: Do you mean $P(X\geq k) $? Looks awfully close to the birthday problem.